# How to unpack an google.protobuf.Any type in gRPC nodejs client?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

My protobuf file is like this:

```
syntax = "proto3"; import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

service RoomService {
    getTestAny (Hotelid) returns (google.protobuf.Any); }

message Hotelid {
    string hotelid = 1; 
} 

message HtlInDate {
    Hotelid hotelid = 1;
    string date = 2; 
}
```

My java-gRPC-server code is like that:

```
@Override
public void getTestAny(Roomservice.Hotelid request, StreamObserver<Any> responseObserver) {

    Roomservice.Hotelid hotelid = Roomservice.Hotelid.newBuilder()
                                             .setHotelid("This is Hotelid")
                                             .build();

    Roomservice.HtlInDate htlDate = Roomservice.HtlInDate.newBuilder()
                                               .setHotelid(hotelid)
                                               .setDate("This is Data")
                                               .build();

    responseObserver.onNext(Any.pack(htlDate));
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
```

And I make a request from a nodejs-gRPC-client, which code is like that:

```
function () {
    var client = new services.RoomServiceClient('localhost:6565',
        grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

    var request = new messages.Hotelid();
    var hotelid = "ignore";

    request.setHotelid(hotelid);

    var call = client.getTestAny(request, function (err, response) {

        var obj = response.toObject();

        console.log(obj);
    });
}
```

The response in nodejs-gRPC-client is a type of Any. And it contains a data array:

```
array:["type.googleapis.com/HtlInDate", Uint8Array[10,17,10...]]
```

I try to use `response.toObject()` to get HtlInDate instance but I just get like this:

```
obj:{
   typeUrl:"type.googleapis.com/HtlInDate",
   value:"ChEKD1RoaXMgaXMgSG90ZWxpZBIMVGhpcyBpcyBEYXRh"
}
```

> So how can I unpack the Any type response and get the HtlInDate instance exactly?   Thanks a lot if you have any idea about this!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the `google.protobuf.Any` type is not supported in Node.js, either in Protobuf.js, which gRPC uses by default, or by google-protobuf, which is the official first party protobuf implementation.

Comment: Is any types from `google.protobuf` supported by Node.js?

Answer (score 2):

From documentation:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#message

```
// Storing an arbitrary message type in Any.
const status = new proto.foo.ErrorStatus();
const any = new Any();
const binarySerialized = ...;
any.pack(binarySerialized, 'foo.Bar');
console.log(any.getTypeName());  // foo.Bar

// Reading an arbitrary message from Any.
const bar = any.unpack(proto.foo.Bar.deserializeBinary, 'foo.Bar');
```

Please take a note that for browser support you need to use webpack(probably with babel loader) or browserify

Answer (score 1):

As found in [google-protobuf tests](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/d16bf914bc5ba569d2b70376051d15f68ce4322d/js/binary/proto_test.js#L657) Any is bundled with pack and unpack functions.

Your code could be unpacked like this:

```js
function () {
    var client = new services.RoomServiceClient('localhost:6565',
        grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

    var request = new messages.Hotelid();
    var hotelid = "ignore";

    request.setHotelid(hotelid);

    var call = client.getTestAny(request, function (err, response) {

        var obj = response.toObject();
        console.log('Any content', obj);

        var date = response.unpack(messages.HtlInDate.deserializeBinary, response.getTypeName());
        console.log('HtlInDate', date.toObject());
    });
}
```

This will deserialize the bytes received in the Any object.

You could also build some Any using pack function for wrapping TypeUrl and Value:

```js
var someAny = new Any();
someAny.pack(date.serializeBinary(), 'HtlInDate')
```