# Can @grpc/grpc-js dynamically unpack google.protobuf.Any type?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node, grpc-js, arduino-cli

I work on a gRPC client using [`@grpc/grpc-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/grpc-js), and I have to handle application-specific errors by reading the `details` array of the [`google.rpc.Status`](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors) object. Is it possible to dynamically `unpack` the error object without knowing the possible errors upfront? The elements of the `details` array are `google.protobuf.Any`.

I am calling a server-streaming [`Init`](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli/blob/e7ba99f4007b5a84a1dabe40598c0c7b49439b51/rpc/cc/arduino/cli/commands/v1/commands.proto#L37-L39) method:

```proto
  // Initializes an existing Arduino Core instance by loading platforms and
  // libraries
  rpc Init(InitRequest) returns (stream InitResponse) {}
```

The [`InitResponse`](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli/blob/e7ba99f4007b5a84a1dabe40598c0c7b49439b51/rpc/cc/arduino/cli/commands/v1/commands.proto#L194-L207) has the following definition:

```proto
message InitResponse {
  message Progress {
    // Progress of the downloads of platforms and libraries index files.
    DownloadProgress download_progress = 1;
    // Describes the current stage of the initialization.
    TaskProgress task_progress = 2;
  }
  oneof message {
    Progress init_progress = 1;
    google.rpc.Status error = 2;
    // Selected profile information
    Profile profile = 3;
  }
}
```

As a client, I do not know what errors can be in the `details` array. Here are a few examples:

```json
{
  "typeUrl": "type.googleapis.com/cc.arduino.cli.commands.v1.PlatformLoadingError",
  "value": ""
}
```

```json
{
  "typeUrl": "type.googleapis.com/cc.arduino.cli.commands.v1.FailedInstanceInitError",
  "value": "CAIStAFMb2FkaW5nIGluZGV4IGZpbGU6IGxvYWRpbmcganNvbiBpbmRleCBmaWxlIC9Vc2Vycy9hLmtpdHRhL0xpYnJhcnkvQXJkdWlubzE1L3BhY2thZ2VfaW5kZXguanNvbjogb3BlbiAvVXNlcnMvYS5raXR0YS9MaWJyYXJ5L0FyZHVpbm8xNS9wYWNrYWdlX2luZGV4Lmpzb246IG5vIHN1Y2ggZmlsZSBvciBkaXJlY3Rvcnk="
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69161608/5529090) SO answer, I learned that I could use `Any#unpack` to get the message object. It works but is not dynamic, and I need to know the possible errors to deserialize it. See an example:

```ts
const error: Status | undefined = resp.getError();
if (error) {
  const details: Any[] = error.getDetailsList();
  if (details.length) {
    const any = details[0];
    const typeName = any.getTypeName();
    switch (typeName) {
      case 'cc.arduino.cli.commands.v1.FailedInstanceInitError': {
        const initError = any.unpack(
          FailedInstanceInitError.deserializeBinary,
          typeName
        );
        console.log('Handle the init error', initError);
        break;
      }
      case 'cc.arduino.cli.commands.v1.PlatformLoadingError': {
        const loadError = any.unpack(
          PlatformLoadingError.deserializeBinary,
          typeName
        );
        console.log('Handle the load error', loadError);
        break;
      }
      default: {
        console.log('Unexpected error');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can I dynamically acquire the deserialize method of the corresponding type from the `typeName`?
According to the [protocolbuffers/protobuf-javascript#68 (comment)](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-javascript/issues/68#issuecomment-1128002015), it's not feasible. How do others do it? What's the best practice if dynamic deserialization is not possible?

Thank you!

---

**Update**

I found a hack, but it works. I leave it here.

I looked into the JS modules generated from the `proto` files and noticed that the `deserializeBinary` is available from the `global` object. They're under the `'proto'` key.

If I write a tiny function with the help of [`get-value`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-value):

```typescript
import { Message } from 'google-protobuf';
import get = require('get-value');

export function globalDeserializeBinary<T extends Message = Message>(
  typeName: string
): ((data: Uint8Array) => T) | undefined {
  return get(global, ['proto', typeName, 'deserializeBinary'].join('.'));
}
```

I can modify my code to this:

```typescript
const error: Status | undefined = resp.getError();
if (error) {
  const details: Any[] = error.getDetailsList();
  if (details.length) {
    const any = details[0];
    const typeName = any.getTypeName();
    const deserialize = globalDeserializeBinary(typeName);
    if (deserialize) {
      const error = any.unpack(deserialize, typeName);
      if (error) {
        console.log('BLABLA', JSON.stringify(error.toObject(false)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will produce the desired objects:

```
BLABLA {"reason":2,"message":"Loading index file: loading json index file /Users/a.kitta/Library/Arduino15/package_index.json: open /Users/a.kitta/Library/Arduino15/package_index.json: no such file or directory"}
BLABLA {"reason":2,"message":"Loading index file: loading json index file /Users/a.kitta/Library/Arduino15/package_teensy_index.json: open /Users/a.kitta/Library/Arduino15/package_teensy_index.json: no such file or directory"}
BLABLA {}
BLABLA {}
```